# No longer able to create bookmarks in Chrome 40.0.2214.115 m

Tags: google-chrome

I am updated to latest Chrome version and I am noticing for the last few days, I am simply not able to create bookmarks by clicking on the star at the right end of address bar, even though there are no updates pending. It has been simply grayed out:

[image]

What's the matter?

Comment: What happens when you press Ctrl+D?

Comment: nothing happens

Comment: Try going to `chrome://extensions` and disable the extension `Bookmarks Manager`

Answer (score 0):

Try to restore Chrome, by going to the directory:

C:\Users(username)\AppData\Local\Google\

Then select and right-click the Folder/Directory "Chrome", once you selected it, click on Properties.

Inside "Chrome Properties" go to the Tab "Previous Versions" go to an earlier date before you remember your could not create bookmarks , select it, click the Button "Restore".

Wait for about 10 to 25 mins and when you open Chrome your Bookmarks will be back.

Now make a Backup of your bookmarks, just in case.